# google earth plugin load 3D model failed

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I have a problem when I load the 3d file, the detailed code is below, who can help me to check why I can't load the 3d model.

```
    function load3D(){

    // Placemark
    var placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
    placemark.setName('model');

    // Placemark/Model (geometry)
    var model = ge.createModel('');


    // Placemark/Model/Link
    var link = ge.createLink('');
    link.setHref('D:/gooleEarthApplication/gooleEarthApplication/3Dsrc/bankright1.dae');
    model.setLink(link);

    // get center look at location
    // Placemark/Model/Location
    var loc = ge.createLocation('');

    loc.setLatitude(30.55423190570);
    loc.setLongitude(114.33491353925);


    model.setLocation(loc);

    // add the model placemark to Earth

    placemark.setGeometry(model);
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);



    var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

    lookAt.setRange(lookAt.getRange() / 20000.0);

    // Set latitude and longitude values
    lookAt.setLatitude(30.55423190570);
    lookAt.setLongitude(114.33491353925);


    // zoom into the model
    lookAt.setRange(300);
    lookAt.setTilt(80);

    ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not load DAE (or KML/KMZ) files from the file system when using the Google Earth plugin. You need to setup a local HTTP server (Apache by ex.) and load the files from a local URL (http://localhost/bankright1.dae)